# 3ds max performance modelling

Tags: performance, webgl, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling

Hy!
I am working with a not well modelled, realy high poly mesh(es).
I have already reduced the vertex, edge numbers using Optimizer and Prooptimizer.
My objects have a hierarchy, and I can select smaller groups.

My question is how can I merge the vertexes of theese without editing manually, because later I will have modells like this, but 10 times bigger.

Also I am open for other solutions, because I want to show theese modells in webgl apps, who knows maybe NURBS from vertex modell.

Or copy naviswork style and make modells 10 times smaller ;).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVoFi2mnyhA

Comment: This seems like the wrong place to ask? You're asking how to model. This is a coding site. Maybe ask on a modeling forum like http://www.polycount.com/forum/